# Determinants of the matrix of a positive defined scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V,g)$ be an eucliden vector space, and $M$ the matrix which represents the positive defined scalar product $g$ with respect to the basis $B=\{u_1,...,u_n\}$. I am asking myself if we can we conclude that $\text{det}M>0$, but I cannot answer. Could you provide a proof (or a counterexample)?

Also, can we say something about the positivity of the determinant of the submatrices of $M$ (something like, $g$ is indeed a positive defined scalar product iff certain submatrices have positive determinant)?

Answer (score 0):

What ur looking for is Sylvesters criterion : M a $n\times n$ symetric matirix is  positive defined iff $\forall k\in [1,n]$ ,the upper left $k\times k$ minor has >0 deteminant.

A proof using a recurrence :

The criterion is true for $n=1$. Assume it's true for a given $n-1$ and let's show that it's true for $n$. Denote by $M_k$ the $k$ minor above.

$\bf{Hint}$

$M_{n-1}$ represent in the basis $u_1,\cdots, u_{n-1}$ the restrection of $g$ to Span$(u_1,\cdots,u_{n-1})$.

Let $v\neq 0$ be an orthogonal vector to $u_1,\cdots,u_{n-1}$. The matrix of $g$ in the basis $(u_1,\cdots,u_{n-1},v)$ is : 
$$M'=\begin{bmatrix} M_{n-1}&0\\0&g(v,v) \end{bmatrix}.$$